# On the group of rotations of a cube

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I would try to prove that the rotational symmetries of the cube are isomorphic to the group of permutations on 4 elements. My attempt is the following:

1. the number of possibile rotation is 24. Easy
2. the group of rotations Acts faithfully on the set of vertices so it's embedded
   in $S_8$.
3. we notice that this subgroup is transitive
   So, i know that i have a transitive subgroup of order 24 in $S_8$, can i conclude that this is $S_4$? Do i need more information on the subgroup?

Comment: Expanding on this, if you have an action of $S^4$ on the group of symmetries, all you need to do is show that it is faithful. In the version you set up, you would need to show that there is no other transitive subgroup of $S^8$ with order $24$, which is probably much more difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Look down on the cube and number the vertices of the upper face as $1, 2, 3$ and $4$ working counterclockwise from the top right. Number each diagonal of the cube $1, 2, 3$ and $4$ according to which vertex on the top face it passes through. With a $90^\circ$ rotation about the vertical axis you can achieve the permutation $g = (1\,2\,3\,4)$ of the diagonals, while with a $90^\circ$ rotation about one of the horizontal axes you can achieve the permutation $h=(1\,4\,2\,3)$. You then have $g^2h = (1\,2)$ and $gh^2 = (1\,3)$. By symmetry, you can achieve any transposition of two diagonals and hence any permutation of the diagonals.

(Alternatively, as you have already calculated that there are $24$ rotations, you can observe that the action of the rotations on the diagonals induces an injective homomorphism of the group of rotations into $S^4$ which must be an isomorphism since both groups have $24$ elements.)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the easiest way to show that the cube rotation group is the group of permutations of 4 elements is to directly show it in fact permutes 4 elements.  This is easy: The 4 elements being permuted are *the cube's major diagonals* (i.e the diagonals through the cube's center).

Any permutation of these diagonals can be achieved using at most three cube rotations:  First, assuming the diagonals are numbered 1-4, rotate the cube around any axis through face centers to move diagonal x into the position of diagonal 1; then rotate the cube about diagonal x to move diagonal y into the position of diagonal 2; finally, rotate the cube about the axis through the center of the cube perpendicular to the plane containing diagonals x and y (hence also through two parallel edges), flipping x any y end-over-end but otherwise leaving x mapped to x and y to y, to swap diagonal z into the position of diagonal 3.